# Prove a set of nowhere differentiable functions in C[0,1] is dense in C[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

Let A={f in C[0,1]: f is nowhere differentiable}. Prove A is dense in C[0,1]. 
This is a test prep question, I am lost on how to start it, so any advice would be good. We have not learned the Baire Category Theorem so I cannot use that to help prove this.

Comment: Do you know that polynomials are dense in your space?

Comment: Yes, I do know that

Answer (score 3):

Let $f\in C[0,1]$ and fix $\delta>0$.

Let $h\in C[0,1]$ be a function that is nowhere differentiable. Using that everywhere differentiable functions are dense (polynomials, for instance), let $f_0$ be everywhere differentiable with $\|f-f_0\|<\delta/2$.

Then $g=f_0+\frac{\delta h}{2\|h\|}$ is nowhere differentiable: if it were differentiable at some point, then so would $h=2\|h\|(g-f_0)/\delta$. And 
$$
\|f-g\|\leq\|f-f_0\|+\|f_0-g\|=\|f-f_0\|+\frac\delta2<\frac\delta2+\frac\delta2=\delta.
$$

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot